# Starting timer when clicking first card of memory game

Tags: javascript, timer, click, event-listener

Ok I am trying to wrap up a project and the only thing holding me back is it that they call for the timer to start on clicking a match game. The timer starts when the HTML file loads which is not what the project wants and I have tried some methods but ends up freezing the game. I want the timer to be able to start when clicking a card.

```
var open = [];
var matched = 0;
var moveCounter = 0;
var numStars = 3;
var timer = {
    seconds: 0,
    minutes: 0,
    clearTime: -1
};

//Start timer
    var startTimer = function () {
        if (timer.seconds === 59) {
            timer.minutes++;
            timer.seconds = 0;
        } else {
            timer.seconds++;
    };


    // Ensure that single digit seconds are preceded with a 0
    var formattedSec = "0";
        if (timer.seconds < 10) {
            formattedSec += timer.seconds
        } else {
            formattedSec = String(timer.seconds);
        }

        var time = String(timer.minutes) + ":" + formattedSec;
        $(".timer").text(time);
    };
```

This is the code for clicking on a card. I have tried to include a startTimer code into this but doesn't work.

```
var onClick = function() {
    if (isValid( $(this) )) {

        if (open.length === 0) {
            openCard( $(this) );

        } else if (open.length === 1) {
            openCard( $(this) );
            moveCounter++;
            updateMoveCounter();

            if (checkMatch()) {
                setTimeout(setMatch, 300);

            } else {
                setTimeout(resetOpen, 700);

            }
        }
    }
};
```

And this class code I use for my HTML file

```
<span class="timer">0:00</span>
```

Comment: Put your code into a plunker codepen or similar and you will likely get much more lucrative responses. There is context missing here which makes it hard to tell whats happening.

Comment: Here the full code in action https://codepen.io/cmandersen/pen/aLWZMb Everything works fine except the timer. The timer is expected to start when a card is clicked and not when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boWQbe

All you needed to do was remove `resetTimer()` call from the function that happens on page load and then just do a check in the `onClick` (of card) to see if the timer has started yet. `timer.seconds == 0 && timer.minutes == 0`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks for the help. Saved a lot of hours and I can focus on the next project.

Comment: @ChadAndersen If you are content with this answer please accept it to help others in the future with the a similar issue.